# How do I cancel all the friend requests I have made on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

If I send many friend requests to someone and afterwards I need to cancel all of them, because if I don't do that I'll be blocked, how do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Click on "Find Friends"

[image: Facebook left panel menu]

Click on "View sent requests"

[image: "Find Friends" main menu]

Open the menu for the request you want to cancel, choose "Cancel Request", and confirm.

[image: "Friend Request" menu]

Facebook does not appear to offer a way to cancel Friend Requests in bulk. You'll need to do it one at a time.